# Losing in_cart state only on certain page refresh

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

So i am currently using states to determine if a user has added an item to their cart or not. It is working almost flawlessly other than when they are on the "Product Page"(The page where they add to cart), and they refresh it empties out the in_cart array, but if im on the home page after adding them i can refresh all i want, this means it has to be something in the product page code but cant figure it out, here is the product page code:

```
const ProductPageBody = ({ products, in_cart, set_in_cart }) => {
  //Keeps track of color user selects
  const [color, setColor] = useState("");
  //Keeps track of size user selects
  const [size, setSize] = useState("Small");

  //Filters out the product that the user selected
  const { shirtName } = useParams();
  const shirt = products.filter((product) => product.name === shirtName);
  //Updates state size of shirt being selected
  const updateSize = () => {
    let select = document.getElementById("sizeSelect");
    let text = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
    setSize(text);
  };

  //Updates state color of shirt being selected
  const updateColor = useCallback(async (userColor, shirt) => {
    const shirtColorSource = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:5000/products/${shirt.product_id}/${userColor}`
    );
    const shirtColor = await shirtColorSource.json();
    console.log(shirtColor);
    shirt.image = shirtColor[0].image;
    setColor(userColor);
  }, []);

  //Occurs when ADD TO CART is clicked
  const updateInCart = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newShirt = { ...shirt[0] };
    newShirt["color"] = color;
    newShirt["size"] = size;
    const newList = in_cart.list.concat(newShirt);
    const cost = newList.reduce((sum, shirt) => sum + shirt.price, 0);
    set_in_cart({
      list: newList,
      totalcost: cost,
    });
  };

  //Stores in cart items
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("inCartItems", JSON.stringify(in_cart));
  }, [in_cart]);
```

and its parent where the state is located:

```
const Routes = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const [in_cart, set_in_cart] = useState({
    list: [],
    totalCost: 0,
  });
  const getProducts = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/products/");
      const jsonData = await response.json();

      setProducts(jsonData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem("inCartItems")) {
      set_in_cart(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("inCartItems")));
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts();
  }, []);
```

any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Looks to be persisted in localStorage in the parent. Is there any logic between the parent and child to also persist cart data?

Comment: @DrewReese Any of the logic between the localStorage of the child and parentt is in the if statement you see in the routes and the useEffect in product page, I just need it where the products wont be deleted on refresh

Comment: Well, that appears to populate the cart *from* localStorage when `Routes` mounts. Any logic later to persist `in_cart` *to* localStorage?

Comment: @DrewReese Nope that is the only connection between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Routes`, add an effect to persist the cart data (`in_cart`) to localStorage when it updates.

```
useEffect(() => {
  try {
    localStorage.setItem("inCartItems", JSON.stringify(in_cart));
  } catch(err) {
    // do something if cart persistence fails
  }
}, [in_cart]);
```